# ActionScript 2 MovieClip Class or Interface Not Found

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

I'm converting an actionscript 3 project to AS2 because AS3 is not yet scaleform compatible in CryEngine 3.

I have a MovieClip in the library. Under ActionScript linkage I have "Export for Actionscript" and "Export in frame 1" set, with the identifier "Notification" and nothing in "Class".

This code results in the error `The class or interface 'Notification' could not be loaded.`

```
var newMovieClip:MovieClip = new Notification();
stage.addChild(newMovieClip);
```

What is wrong with this code? It seems like a simple operation to create a MovieClip and add it to the stage, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ActionScript 2 you need to use the `attachMovie` method (see [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001278.html)). Your code would look something like this:

```
var newMovieClip:MovieClip = this.attachMovie("Notification", "newMovieClip", this.getNextHighestDepth());
```

Note that there's no `addChild` method in ActionScript 2; the `displayList` was added in ActionScript 3.